# Bayes' theorem to find $P(A\cap B), \,P(B\mid A),\,P(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

> Given, $P(A)=0.4, P(B)=0.5,P(A\mid B)=0.3 $.
>
> Need to find $$P(A\cap B), \,P(B\mid A),\,P(A\cup B).$$

So far I did $$P(A\cap B) = P(A\mid B) P(B) = 0.15.$$

And I have the formula $$P(B\mid A)= \frac{P(A\mid B)P(B)}{P(A\mid B)P(B) + P(A\mid\bar B)P(\bar B)}$$

How do I find $P(A|\bar B)$? And what is the formula for $P(A\cup B)$? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach.

From 
$$
P_{B}(A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$ you deduce that
$$
P(A\cap B)=P(B)\times P_{B}(A)
$$ giving 
$$
P(A\cap B)=0.5\times0.3=\color{blue}{0.15}
$$ From 
$$
P_{A}(B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}
$$ you deduce that
$$
P_{A}(B)=\frac{0.15}{0.4}=\color{blue}{0.375}
$$ On the other hand, we have
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)
$$ giving
$$
P(A\cup B)=0.4+0.5-0.15=\color{blue}{0.75}.
$$ You may notice that
$$
P_{\overline{B}}(A)=\frac{P(A\cap \overline{B})}{P(\overline{B})}=\frac{P(A)-P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)}=\frac{0.4-0.15}{0.85}=\color{blue}{\frac{5}{17}}\approx \color{blue}{0.2941}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Really appreciated.